# Deleted OS from my device

Tags: system-error, htc-one-s

I accidentally deleted all data from my htc one s, including the operating system. I tried to delete photos,apps and downloads, but it was still showing a memory issue (my phone has 16 giga memory and the "others" were using 10GB of it so i couldn't download more apps) and my phone was running very slow and even had some black outs.

I have team win on my phone. I went to factory reset which lead me to team win, and I choose to delete everything and didn't realize there was operating system in it too.

How can I reinstall my Android OS?

Answer (score 1):

Download an image of Android for your phone on your sd card, and boot into Team Win.
There you will find Install button, then choose an image you downloaded on your sd card.

Comment: So this is how i can istall an operating system back to my phone? :S

Comment: Or should i dowload an os to my computer and transfer it? :P

Comment: @helen you should download an image on your computer(well, you cannot install from the phone anyways) and copy the image to microsd card(hopefully your phone has it)

Comment: @helen also make sure if you have a backup on your phone, search for TWRP folder, make sure you're able to see hidden files & folders as well. If you have a backup file it will ease restoring so much